# Fingerprint scanner on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, fingerprint

I have a couple of Fingerprint scanners (for example the EgisTek 603) which I originally bought for windows 7.  I stopped using them a few years ago and lost the keys that came with the software.  Now, I'm back on Windows 7 at work and would like to use them.

I can see I can use Windows Hello on Win 10, but I'm not in Win 10.  EgisTek won't talk to me so I can't use the BioExcess app that came with the product as I don't have the keys anymore.

Is there a way to interface with the scanners in Windows 7 (e.g., does Windows 7 include a generic driver or a utility equivalent to Windows Hello)?

Comment: Do you still have the original computer it was used on (you might be able to recover the key)?

Comment: Only Windows 8.x+ has Fingerprint scanner compatibility built-in.  Only Windows 10, has Windows Hello, which supports compatible fingerprint scanners

Comment: @fixer1234 - yes, but it's in pieces...  and it may not be the exact one.  This is going back a few years! :)

Comment: If you still have the hard drive intact, a program like Belarc Adviser may be able to read the key.  If nobody suggests fingerprint software here, you could ask on software recs.